# Resizing PHP image file

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP function that resizes an image.

**PHP config:**

```
$file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

    getimagesize('../uploaded/'.$file);
```

Why does the function `getimagesize()` return an array?

- I want to get the width and height of the uploaded photo and change them to a specified pixel value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), `getimagesize` function will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and the correspondant HTTP content type.

Index 0 and 1 contain respectively the width and the height of the image.

```
$info = getimagesize('../uploaded/'.$file);
$width = $info[0];
$height = $info[1];
```